# Move sequentially from one sub to the next sub, ADDED missing Sub aMoveHTotals() in original post

Tags: excel, vba, call

I have used different methods of moving from one sub to the next or another sub with no problem. however I  am having trouble getting this one to work

I have used CALL, GOTO, MOVE RANGE, FIND, not having luck.
I am wondering if I am clashing with another variable or range.
I have included the code from the previous and next sub. I have about 300 lines of code in the project so far.
The SUB ColAInsertrow() is the SUB that will not move to SUB aMoveHTotals

```
Sub aGToOColDelete() 
    Range("g1:g1000000").Clear
    Range("i1:i1000000").Clear
    Range("j1:j1000000").Clear
    Range("k1:k1000000").Clear
    Range("l1:l1000000").Clear
    Range("m1:m1000000").Clear
    Range("n1:n1000000").Clear
    Range("o1:o1000000").Clear
    Call ColAInsertrow
End Sub

Sub ColAInsertrow() '===================================yay
    
    'Declare Variables
    Dim LastRow As Long, FirstRow As Long
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim moveHTotalsexit As String
    
    With ActiveSheet
        'Define First and Last Rows
        FirstRow = 1
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        
        'Loop Through Rows (Bottom to Top)
        For Row = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
            If .Range("A" & Row).Value <> "" Then
                If InStr(.Range("A" & Row).Value, "Transactions for") > 0 Then
                    .Range("A" & Row).EntireRow.Insert
                ElseIf .Range("A" & Row).Value = ("Start") Then GoTo moveHTotalsexit
                    
                End If
            End If
        Next Row
        
    End With
    
moveHTotalsexit:
    'Call aMoveHTotals
    Exit Sub
    Call aMoveHTotals
End Sub

Sub aMoveHTotals()'I LEFT THIS OUT OF MY FIRST POST   ***
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet'   ***
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange'   ***
    
    aMoveHTotalsx rg, "Date:  8/30/2023", 1, , 0, True'   ***
       
End Sub  '   ***

Sub aMoveHTotals( _
    ByVal searchRange As Range, _
    ByVal SearchPattern As String, _
    ByVal SearchColumn As Long, _
    Optional ByVal RowOffset As Long = 0, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnOffset As Long = 0, _
    Optional ByVal ShowMessages As Boolean = False)
    'Argumented (An Improvement) - A Method
    Const MoveHTotalsX As String = "Totals for date:*"
```

Comment: What do you try accomplishing? Firstly, no need to use `Call aMoveHTotals`. It would be enough to use only `aMoveHTotals`, but the call is wrong anyhow... Since the respective sub has 6 arguments, only three of them being `Optional`, **you must call the function using AT LEAST this first three parameters**. Something as `aMoveHTotals Range("Xx:Yx"), "myPattern", 2`. Besides that, using `Exit Sub` before calling the respective `Sub` it is not possible to do it. You commented the code line before it (`'Call aMoveHTotals`)...

Answer (score 0):

`Exit Sub` immediately exits the Sub procedure. It is before `Call ..`.

btw, it's better to keep `GoTo moveHTotalsexit` in a new line although it works in your code.

```vb
        'Loop Through Rows (Bottom to Top)
        For Row = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
            If .Range("A" & Row).Value <> "" Then
                If InStr(.Range("A" & Row).Value, "Transactions for") > 0 Then
                    .Range("A" & Row).EntireRow.Insert
                ElseIf .Range("A" & Row).Value = "Start" Then 
                    GoTo moveHTotalsexit  ' **                    
                End If
            End If
        Next Row
        
    End With
    
moveHTotalsexit:
    'Call aMoveHTotals
    ' Exit Sub ' **
    Call aMoveHTotals
```

Comment: taller_ExcelHome, well it works, I had a missing SUB  aMoveHTotals() after Sub ColAInsertrow(). lost it editing or rearranging Subs , and in frustration added exit sub. Pays to read code further on past a Sub to ensure its going where you want it to.